# Weak Reference on Locale in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection, weak-references

Please check this code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Locale loc = null;
WeakReference<Locale> locWeak = new WeakReference<Locale>(loc);
String country = locWeak.get().getDisplayCountry(new Locale("", tm.getSimCountryIso()));
Log.i(TAG,"Country is: "+country);
```

The `WeakReference` is a bit useless in here as I make a strong reference in "new Locale".

Can anyone please suggest a better approach to `WeakReference` for something like this:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("",tm.getSimCountryIso());
```

The reason I use `WeakReference`, is because I don't need to hang on to this `Object` as it become useless as the app progresses. Secondly, I need to keep a clean memory as I will need to do some heavy tasks later on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone checking this:

After my research on the similar subject, I came up with the conclusion that using `WeakReference` at this function is more expensive in memory than using `StrongReference`.

Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975197/415038 it is another question of mine on this matter. Good complete answers are there.